# Setting value of dynamically generated drop down selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a drop down select menu that is generated dynamically. Its generated using the html select syntax which is then simply inserted using the .after method. And then I use ajax call to get elements of the selector and fill it like this.

```
 $($.parseJSON(msg)).map(function () {
      return $('<option>').val(this.id).text(this.name);
  }).appendTo('#item');
```

Now After this code populates the 'item' drop down menu I have to set it to the some element, say the fifth. So I tried to do it like this.

```
$('#item').val('5');
```

I have even tried to specifically identify the item. Since its in html table, like this.

```
$("#itemTable > tfoot > tr.items").find("td:eq(0) [name='item']").val('5');
```

The above code works fine in other situations when I have a drop down manually created. So I figured both the above attempts are not actually identifying the 'item' drop down component. So is there any other way I can try this?

Comment: btw i have tried to see the value of 'item' after the above code and it returns 5. But it is not displayed in UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jquery documentations for [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) says: "If you wish to process a plain array or object, use the jQuery.map() instead."

Your dropdown will not get populated (check console for errors) and so setting any value to #item will not work.

Try this:

```
var options = $.map($.parseJSON(msg), function (n, i) {
    return $('<option>').val(n.id).text(n.name);
});
$("#item").append(options);
```

With this code, **drowdown will get populated** and then `$("#item").val("5")` will work.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6Us9N/

Comment: Actually populating my drop down works just fine. What I am struggling with setting specific value after the population. But I am happy to try your suggestion.

Comment: Sure thing man! when the drop down is created manual like that it works. I have even used it repeatedly. But my drop down is created in the fly. I will try to create a jsfiddle...hold on

Comment: Looks like I have missed something in my code cause i couldn't replicate the error here. i have merged your code with mine and it works nicely. Thanks anyho!  http://jsfiddle.net/6Us9N/1/

Comment: I see you are creating multiple select boxes with same id. remember id  is unique, so "item" id is set to first select box only. why do you have multiple select boxes by the way?

Comment: I allowed the user to select multiple items now I am trying to retrieve these values and set on each of the drop downs. I am also thinking about changing the ids, may be based on each index. Thanks again!